# Took apart bathroom outlet now I can't get it back together again

Tags: electrical, bathroom, switch, receptacle

I was getting a reverse neutral on bathroom outlet so I took it apart to fix it but now I don't know how to put it back together again.

[image: wiring diagram]

Comment: What are the wires coming out the bottom of the box and where do they go?

Comment: What are the grey outlet terminals connected to?

Comment: Are you sure that power goes to the light first and not to the switches?

Comment: Originally did one switch control the light and the other control the fan?

Comment: I assume your thin line going from breaker to light to fan is NOT  meant to indicate wires but just to signify that the light and fan are on the same breaker, right? Are the black, green and white wires at the bottom the line hot, ground and neutral? If so, there would have to be a neutral which would be probably be a white going from the switch box to the light/fan.

Comment: Assuming the black is the line hot (through the breaker) and the receptacle is unswitched, the black must go to the receptacle on the side with the shorter slot and the white goes to the other side. The black also goes to one side of each switch (which you indicate it does now).  The red will be attached to the other side of one switch as a switched hot to either the light or the fan, and another wire will be attached to the  other side as a switched hot. There must be a neutral from the switch box to the light/fan.

Comment: Moderators curb your robot. Absolutely NO discussion is taking place in this thread.

Comment: Is the house wiring NM cable or wires pulled in conduit?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: You show a red wire at the light, but not the switch.  We don't know where the other end is.  Same with yellow. You don't show what color wires go to the fan.  You show black and white going to the switch box but if the dots represent what's connected where, you show grey and yellow wires connected .. not the same colors as the wires you show entering the box.  It's all confusing.  Photos of all boxes clearly showing wire connections and routing would be very helpful.  Wires unwound to show what cables they go to, all in focus and uniformly lit by the same light to show colors consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your thin line going from breaker to light to fan is NOT meant to indicate wires but just to signify that the light and fan are on the same breaker, are the black, green and white wires at the bottom the line hot, ground and neutral? If so, there would have to be a neutral which would be probably be a white going from the switch box to the light/fan.

Assuming the black is the line hot (from the breaker) and the receptacle is unswitched (always on), the black must go to the receptacle on the side with the shorter slot and the white goes to the other side.

The black also goes to one side of each switch (which you indicate it does now). The red will be attached to the other side of one switch as a switched hot to either the light or the fan, and another wire will be attached to the other side of the other switch as a switched hot.

There must be a neutral from the switch box to the light/fan that connects to the white neutral in the switch box.

Comment: You're wasting your time making assumptions and guessing. Querent's diagram indicates that power goes first to the light and first to the switches. Useless.